# request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I need to send data as **json** with **requests** module in **Python**.

**For example:**

```
import json
import requests
f = requests.Session()
data = {
    "from_date": "{}".format(from_date),
    "to_date": "{}".format(to_date),
    "Action": "Search"
}

get_data = f.post(URL, json=data, timeout=30, verify=False)
```

**But after run this code, it showed this error:**

> ```
> get_data = f.post(URL, json=data, timeout=30, verify=False)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 497, in post
> return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
> TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'
> ```

I'm on `Ubuntu 16.04` and my Python version is `2.7.6`

How to issue this problem?

Comment: Upgrade `requests`, your version is too old.

Comment: @GhostlyMartijn Hi, How to upgrade `requests` ?

Comment: how did you install it? As a system package? What version of Ubuntu? You could install a new version into a virtualenv.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

your data is a dict, you should convert it to json format like this:

json.dumps(data)

```
import json
import requests
f = requests.Session()

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
my_data = {
"from_date": "{}".format(from_date),
"to_date": "{}".format(to_date),
"Action": "Search"
 }

get_data = f.post(URL, data=json.dumps(my_data), timeout=30, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Comment: Hi, Don't work json.dumps(my_data). after get data show `response [415]`.

Comment: @mySun : 415 means that the media type is unsupported. The most likely case is that you are either missing the Content-Type header in your request, or it's incorrect.( not for my code!! or any bug!!! that website or url do not get your json format ) my code is correct! i answered your question about unexpected keyword argument 'json' plz tick me :)

Comment: I run my code on my Laptop and works easily, But after upload on server show this error ! :-(

Comment: @mySun: try it again! i added headers ... tag

Comment: Thank you so much for help me :-)

Comment: As of requests 2.4.2, released 3 years ago, you can use the `json` argument to have the data encoded to JSON for you (plus have the right content type header set). The OP simply has an older version.

Comment: See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)
I suspect that your `json` keyword should actually be `data`, i.e.,

```
get_data = f.post(URL, data=data, timeout=30, verify=False)
```

Comment: Hi, Don't work json.dumps(my_data). after get data show response [415]

Comment: No, `json` is correct for any version of requests released in the last 3 years, as of 2.4.2.

Comment: See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests